# redis connection factory - will this cause memory leaks?

Tags: javascript, typescript, redis, node-redis

I hope someone can give me some advice

I have created a module, that basically creates a redis connection using a singleton pattern which also uses promises.

However, before I return the redis connection, I first check if the connection is ready, on the ready event, I resolve the promise and likewise on any errors, I reject the promise.

My only concern is with this method, can I introduce memory leaks as the listeners function on ready and error may continue listening well after the promise has completed and should be cleaned up by the garbage collector.

I am not sure if this will create some kind of memory leaks..

Any advice would be much appreciated.

```
   

    import redis from 'redis';
       import redisearch from 'redis-redisearch';
    
       redisearch(redis);
    
       let redisClient: redis.RedisClient = null;
    
    
       export function getRedisClient(): Promise {
    
    
        return new Promise((resolve: any, reject: any) => {
    
            if (redisClient && redisClient.connected) {
                return resolve(redisClient);
            }
    
            redisClient = redis.createClient({
    
                password: process.env.REDIS_PASSWORD,
    
                retry_strategy: function (options) {
                    if (options.error && options.error.code === "ECONNREFUSED") {
                        // End reconnecting on a specific error and flush all commands with
                        // a individual error
                        return new Error("The server refused the connection");
                    }
                    if (options.total_retry_time > 1000 * 60 * 60) {
                        // End reconnecting after a specific timeout and flush all commands
                        // with a individual error
                        return new Error("Retry time exhausted");
                    }
                    if (options.attempt > 10) {
                        // End reconnecting with built in error
                        return undefined;
                    }
                    // reconnect after
                    return Math.min(options.attempt * 100, 3000);
                },
            });
    
            redisClient.on("ready", function (error: any) {
                console.log("connection is good");
                return resolve(redisClient);
            });
    
            redisClient.on("error", function (error: any) {
                console.log("reject error");
                if (redisClient) {
                    redisClient.end(false);
                    redisClient = null;
                    return reject(error);
                }
    
            });
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This pattern can create multiple `redisClient`s if `getRedisClient` is called multiple times before any of the `redisClient`s finish connecting. A slightly simpler pattern might be to cache a `Promise<RedisClient>` rather than the `redisClient`:

```js
let redisClientP: Promise<RedisClient>;
function getRedisClient (): Promise<RedisClient> {
  if (redisClientP) return redisClientP;
  redisClientP = new Promise(...previous code)
  return redisClientP;
}
```

If you haven't seen this type of cached `Promise` usage before, here's a small snippet demonstrating that you can access the `.then` on a `Promise` multiple times.

```js
const p = new Promise((resolve) => resolve(2));


(async function main () {
  for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    console.log(i, await p); 
  }
})()
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Willis, but if I cache a promise and call it again, it will no longer respond ? a promise can only resolve once per my understanding

Comment: A promise can only _resolve_ once, but it can have its `.then` called multiple times & each caller of `.then` will be given the resolved value. Does that make senes? I edited to add another example demonstrating the concept. A promise boils down to an object vaguely like `{then: () => resolvedValue, cache: () => thrownValue}`

Comment: Thanks very much, that makes sense :)) I am still a bit confused though, if the redisClient is closed and I always get the same Promise, I would never be able to get a fresh connection if the Redis connection has dropped or dead ? or am I missing something ?

Comment: You understand it perfectly: if the redis client is closed, you can set `redisClientP = null` to recreate it (the old redis client will not get garbage collected because of its listeners), or you can rely on the retry logic to maintain a connection. I'll often set up a single client to connect to a database, and rely on that client's connection logic to maintain that connection. If there's something going wrong with connecting to a database, recreating the client isn't likely to help.

Comment: You have been amazing, thanks very much for your help :).. So ultimately, I don't need the complication, I should just use one connection and leave it at that.. I think I will do this :)